# Save as dialog defaulting in Documents folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report in which I allow multiple users to generate their specific version and then save the file but I do not want them to overwrite my master file.

So I created a save-as dialog that saves the file with a specific name (the parameters after `.show` property are just different parts of the file name).

But the dialog allows users to save the file in the same folder I have the master file by default and I would like to change this to by default offering Documents folder. Is there a way to change this?

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show FYandQName & " " & _
    CountryName & " " & BusValue & " " & "Financial Narratives"
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you show the dialog rather than saving the file directly yourself?

Comment: I want to offer them possibility to rename the file as they like and also to choose their own location if they use other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim s As String
'assuming an .xlsx file
s = FYandQName & " " & CountryName & " " & BusValue & " " & "Financial Narratives.xlsx"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) 
        .InitialFileName = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & s
        .Show
        .Execute
End With
```