# VBA ChDrive/ChDir does not work if the file is saved

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, ms-office

If you run the following VBA Code in any Office application Word/Excel/Access it does not change the default path if the file in which the code resides is saved:

I've tested it on Windows 10, MS-Office 2010 x86, 2016 Plus x86 and O365 x64

1. For example create a new Excel file without saving it!
2. Put the following code in a module or worksheet/workbook-module.
3. Run the code
   The result is: the dialogbox opens your windows-user folder.
4. Now save the file somewhere.
5. Run the code again.
   The result is: the dialogbox does not opens your windows-user folder.!

You could do the test with some other folders/drives. The result is the same - at least on my PCs.

```
Sub ChangeDefaultPath()

' For me are these two lines of code importent.
' Why they do not work as they should.
ChDrive "C"
ChDir "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME")

' This line of code is just for testing. 
' You could comment it out and use F12 or save as from the application menue manually.
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

End Sub
```

Is this issue known? Is there a fix for that without workarounds?

Thanks for any hints and helps.

Comment: You probably want `InitialFileName` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974115/save-as-dialog-defaulting-in-documents-folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is a workaround which I don't intend. The code above is just an example. In fact showing dialogs is just for testing purposes. The topic is about ChDrive and ChDir, why the do not wort as they supposed to do.

Comment: Relaying on current directory `ChDir` is a bad habit! If your code saves  in a specific folder, or launch such a dialog where to browse, that folder becomes the current directory. Firstly, how do you intend to use that active directory? Why don't you, for instance, place that folder path in a variable and use it when needed? `Dim curDir As String` `CurDir = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME")`...

Comment: @FaneDuru No it should be a help for the user. The document does not get automatically saved. The user could press Ctrl+F12 or invoke the application menue save as.

But it is a fundamental problem - why ChDrive and ChDir do not work as they should do? This is the main question.

Comment: I am afraid that Excel works **as it should**, not as **you think it should**. Even the meaning of current directory guides to the **last used folder**. It is the directory **where you are currently working**, by definition! If you want it acting differently, this will not affect the way Excel works... So the 'fundament' of the 'fundamental problem' looks to be wrong... There are other ways to accomplish what you want, but you need to firstly explain what is it about.

Comment: @FaneDuru I think we talk about two different things. In my question above there are five steps. The question is, why ChDrive/ChDir works in the 3. step as expected but in the 5. step it doesn't. The only difference between the 3. and 5. step is that the file is in the 3. step unsaved and in the 5. step it is saved.
It is not a problem about Excel. The question is about those two lines in VBA in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'M not sure but there is a difference between curdir and Application.DefaultFilePath

```
Sub ToCheck()
Dim s As String
s = Application.DefaultFilePath
Debug.Print s

ChDrive "C:\"
ChDir "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME")
Debug.Print CurDir

Application.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME")
Debug.Print Application.DefaultFilePath
' Now check a saving dialog or anything else


' Set back
Application.DefaultFilePath = s ' Set back
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you are right. There is a different between curDir and DefaultFilePath. However both do not change the Path if you add the show dialog line or use F12 or go to menue save as.